# How to get the best trained model from AWS StepFunctions TuningStep with SageMaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I've been pondering on it for a while, and I can't seem to be able to get the best trained model from a `stepfunctions.steps.TuningStep`. I need it for a workflow:

```
workflow_definition = steps.Chain(
    [etl_step, tuning_step, model_step, lambda_step, check_accuracy_step]
)
```

In the documentation:

https://aws-step-functions-data-science-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker.html#stepfunctions.steps.sagemaker.TuningStep

there is no method similar to
`get_expected_model(model_name=None)`
from TrainingStep.
On the other hand, if I use a sagemaker.workflow.steps TuningStep there are ways to obtain the best model:

```
get_top_model_s3_uri()
get_expected_model()
```

Am I missing something or is that really impossible?

Comment: can you not get it from the `tuning_step.tuner`? it should have a `best_estimator()` and `best_training_job()` methods

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I had tried that too. ```tuning_step.tuner.best_estimator()``` returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'best_estimator',  and ```tuner.best_estimator()``` returns ValueError: No tuning job available

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue some time ago, but I'm working directly with the JSON definition of the step function.

In order to retrieve the best trained model I had to do a workaround with a lambda function:

```
import boto3

sm_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

def get_parameter(key, event):
    parameter_value = None
    if (key in event):
        parameter_value = event[key]

    else:
        raise KeyError('{} key not found in function input!'.format(key)+
                      ' The input received was: {}.'.format(event))
    
    return parameter_value


#Retrieve training job name from event and create a model.
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = None

    print(event)

    job_name = get_parameter('TrainingJobName', event)

    response = sm_client.describe_training_job(TrainingJobName=job_name)

    #model_name = get_parameter('ModelName', event)
    #code_path = get_parameter('CodePath', event)
    
    try:
    
        response = sm_client.describe_training_job(TrainingJobName=job_name)
        model_data = response['ModelArtifacts']['S3ModelArtifacts']
        container = response['AlgorithmSpecification']['TrainingImage']
        role_arn = response['RoleArn']
    
        print("Training job: {} has artifacts at: {}.".format(job_name, model_data))
    
    except Exception as e:
        response = ('Failed to read training job artifacts!'+ 
                    ' The training job may not exist or the job name may be incorrect.'+ 
                    ' Check SageMaker to confirm the job name.')
        print(e)
        print('{} Attempted to read job name: {}.'.format(response, job_name))

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'TrainedModelArtifactS3Uri': model_data,
        'TrainingImageUri': container,
        'TrainingJobName': job_name,
        'TrainingRoleArn': role_arn,
    }
```

The lambda function is used as follows:

1. Either the Training Job or HPO Job have an output path `"$.BestTrainingJob.TrainingJobName"` in case of HPO or `"$.TrainingJobName"`.
2. With the trained model artifact S3 Uri, you can concatenate to following states with the output of the lambda function.

The parameters used in the step function to invoke the step function (preceding a training or hpo step) are the following:

```
"Parameters": {
        "FunctionName":  "your-lambda-function-name",
        "Payload": {
          "TrainingJobName.$": "$.BestTrainingJob.TrainingJobName"
        }
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Model evaluation"
```

Note here that the `Payload` has a `.$` after the name. This indicated that it may receive intrinsic functions and JSONPath referring to the preceding step.

Hopefully this helps!